# How to lookup a Class from Child project in java?

Tags: java

I have project named `A` and another project named `B`, and `B` extends `A` (`B` has `A` as a dependency). Now, I have a service class names `S` in project `B`. I would like to call the service `S` from `A`. Is there any way to implement that?

Comment: Nope if you are talking about actual dependencies.

Comment: @MuratK. yes, I think so, I got that kind of question in an interview.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with dependencies. However if both projects were to depend on each other, it is called a `cyclic dependency`, and is a problem that needs to be solved.